# Interpretation of transpose of a linear application from a matricial product point of view

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, bilinear-form, transpose

From this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58146/transpose-of-a-linear-mapping), I saw :

1. > If $f: V→W$ is a linear map between vector spaces $V$ and $W$ with
   >   nondegenerate bilinear forms, we define **[the transpose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose#Transpose_of_linear_maps)** of $f$
   >   to be
   >   the linear map $^tf : W→V$, determined by
   >   $$B_V(v,{}^tf(w))=B_W(f(v),w) \quad \forall\ v \in V, w \in W.$$
   >   Here,
   >   $B_V$ and $B_W$ are the bilinear forms on $V$ and $W$
   >   respectively.
   >   The matrix of the transpose of a map is the transposed matrix only
   >   if
   >   the bases are orthonormal with respect to their bilinear forms.
2. > If $f : V → W$ is a linear map, then **[the transpose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_space#Transpose_of_a_linear_map)** (or dual)
   >   $f^*
   > : W^* → V^*$ is defined by $$f^*(\varphi) = \varphi \circ f \, $$
   >   for
   >   every $φ ∈ W^*$.  If the linear map $f$ is represented by the
   >   matrix
   >   $A$ with respect to two bases of $V$ and $W$, then $f^*$ is
   >   represented by the transpose matrix $A^T$ with respect to the dual
   >   bases of $W^*$ and $V^*$.

I would like to get more precisions between these 2 definitions :

**1.Question :** Does [Riesz theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem) make the link between these 2 definitions above ? i.e between the definition involving the inner product and the other one involving the notion of dual linear map ?

If I take the following formula expressing the inner product $(.|.)$ between 2 vectors $X,\,Y \in V$ (for a matricial product point of view) :

$(X|Y) = X^{T}\,M\,Y$ with $$M$$ the matrix associated to the inner product, i.e $$M=\text{Mat}_{V}(e_i\cdot e_j)$$ ,

**2.Question :** Can I consider the product $$X^{T}\,M$$ like a dual linear form such the formula $$(X|Y)$$ represents the action of the linear form $$X^{T}\,M$$ on vector $$Y$$ ?

I don't know what's the english for "crochet de dualité" (french, maybe `bracket of duality` ?) that expresses simply the "dot-product" between a linear form `l` and a vector `v` : `<l,v>=l(v)`

Now, I would like to use the definition of the transpose application to visualize it with matrices product : the adjoint of matrix $A$ is noted $A^{*}$ and defined by :

$$\forall\ X, Y \in V : (AX|Y) = (X|A^{*}Y)$$

I consider real coefficients for matrix $A$. If basis is orthonormal, I have $$M$$ matrix equal to $$I_{d}$$ (identity matrix).

So, I have with product of matrices :

$(AX|Y) = X^{T}\,A^{T}\,I_{d}\,Y = (X|A^{*}Y) = X^{T}\,I_{d}\,A^{*}\,Y$

$=X^{T}\,A^{*}\,Y$

So I deduce $$A^{*}=A^{T}$$

But as you can see, I presupposed the rule for the transpose of a product, i.e $$(AX)^{T}=X^{T}A^{T}$$

**3.Question :** If someone could give me another demonstration or a way to visualize well the notion of transpose linear map, this would be nice to give it.

**4.Question :** a last question : in my definition of adjoint $A^{*}$ with inner product, is it always necessary to have an orthonormal basis ? because if this is not the case, I can only have the following equality :

$$(AX|Y) = X^{T}\,A^{T}\,M\,Y = (X|A^{*}Y) = X^{T}\,M\,A^{*}\,Y$$

$$\Rightarrow\quad\quad  A^{T}\,M = M\,A^{*}$$

i.e not directly $A^{T} = A^{*}$.

Thanks for your help

Comment: 1. Yes, but you need to discuss continuity in the infinite dimensional case.

Comment: 3. You might see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2392454/8157).

Comment: 4. Yes, the matrix must be computed in an orthonormal basis.

Comment: -@Giuseppe Negro Thanks for your remarks. About Question 4, what does happen when the $M$ matrix (that can be assimilated to "metric" = $$g_{ij}=e_i\cdot e_j$$) is not orthogonal, i.e different from matrix identity ? Indeed, I can deduce only that $A^{T}\,M=M\,A^{*}$ ? are there other relations or conclusions starting from this later equality ?

Comment: I agree on the formula $A^TM=MA^\star$. Why are you not satisfied? Depending on what you do, that formula can be useful or not. If you find it useful someday, you will extract more information from it.